# Retrieve childs name Firebase Database Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm looking to retrieve the names of all the child of a section in my Firebase Database. Then I want to put them in an array.

```
{
  "sVkyFjTI9yOTlOPFzUv5MvFozlh2" : {
    "groups" : {
      "group 1" : "9FA02017-172B-434B-A873-518854697CCC",
      "group 2" : "B52743E0-8441-40FB-98BA-51920F31EFE6",
      "group 3" : "1A320965-88A3-42FF-A917-0D93BE39B357"
    }
  }
}
```

I've done this already:

```
ref.child("user_profile").child(user!.uid).child("groups/").observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
        if !snapshot.exists() { return }
        let groupDict = snapshot.value! as? [string]
})
```

But I only need the child names in an array (here: 'group 1','group 2','group 3') and not the values of them. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You've included a (link to a) picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export button in your Firebase Database console. Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: Aside from that: `snapshot.key!` will give you the key of the item.

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't work! I only get the name of the parent: "groups"

Comment: Ah, you want each child. Loop over the snapshot children with `for childSnapshot in snapshot.children { print(childSnapshot.key) }`

Comment: Can you please copy my initial function and add your corrections because I'm lost ahah :D. Thx for the help.

Comment: I got this but this give me an error... `ref.child("user_profile").child(user!.uid).child("groups/").observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: {for childSnapshot in snapshot.children
            
            {
                print(childSnapshot.key)
            }
        
        })`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I used this code and it's work perfectly:
    var ref = Firebase(url: "https://.firebaseio.com/restaurants/")

```
ref.child("user_profile").child(user!.uid).child("groups").observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: {
        snapshot in
        var groupNames = [String]()
        for group in snapshot.children {
            groupNames.append(group.key)
        }
        print(groupNames)
    })
```